# infix to postfix converter using stack

Tags: c++

I want to convert infix to postfix expression. This is my code:

The problem is that this actually doesn't do so and I am confused why. Everything makes sense to me but when i input for example `4*5` as an output i get the same thing. infix is an input and postfix is what i want to return as a pointer to postfix so it can be then evaluated.

operand returns true if it is * - + or /

UPDATE:

oki i got it working but i have trouble figuring out what if you input like  5 * 3 + -1.2 then its not gonna work if you want to have like negative number.

```
void infix2postfix(char* infix, char* postfix){
     char *in,*post;
        Stack<char>Q;
        char n;
        in = &infix[0];
        post = &postfix[0];
        while(*in){
            while(*in == ' ' || *in == '\t'){
                in++;
            }
            if( isdigit(*in) || isalpha(*in) ){
                while( isdigit(*in) || isalpha(*in)){
                    *post = *in;
                    post++;
                    in++;
                }
            }
            if( *in == '(' ){
                Q.Push(*in);
                in++;
            }
            if( *in == ')'){
                n = Q.Pop();
                while( n != '(' ){
                    *post = n;
                    post++;
                    n = Q.Pop();
                }
                in++;
            }
            if( operand(*in) ){
                if(Q.IsEmpty())
                    Q.Push(*in);
                else{
                    n = Q.Pop();
                    while(priority(n) >= priority(*in)){
                        *post = n;
                        post++;
                        n = Q.Pop();
                    }
                    Q.Push(n);
                    Q.Push(*in);
                }
                in++;
            }
        }
        while(!Q.IsEmpty())
        {
            n = Q.Pop();
            *post = n;
            post++;

        }
        *post = '\0';
    }
```

here is my code new code, it works but I want it to to work with unary operators so it would take the input `4 * 5 + 4 + -1.2`, so there is a space between and if there is not then it is for example -1.2 negative number. also my code doesn't work for an integer which is more than 9, if i put 10 then it just multiplies 1*0.
.

Comment: Try debugging your code? In visual studio you can press F10 to execute your code line by line.

Comment: @AtoMerZ I tried it but I am not really got at it.

Comment: When I have such problems I try executing my code line by line as suggested before. Carefully watching variable values and expected behavior. Eventually I find the error spot.

Comment: Does it have to be one stack? Or is it okay to use two stacks? Also, is there a reason you don't you use the standard [`std::stack`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack)?

Comment: 1. i was asked to implement stack (the stack functions are fine i checked it ). 2. I think it was kind of more straightforward using one stack, and i really want to keep it one stack because i have done some other functions associated with one stack.

Comment: You should also look over your `for` loops, the order of the expression in it is wrong. Also, `infix` will not be `NULL` for a looong while, I think you mean `*infix != '\0'`.

Comment: i tried it, it doesn't work

Comment: @JackF: you may not be good at it, but how will you *become* good at it if you don't do it? I'm sure at some point you weren't good at riding a bicycle, playing basketball, talking to girls or whatever.

Comment: @JackF Nobody's born with debugging skills, we all try. Putting the burden on other people is not a practical solution.

Comment: i got it working but i have problem with things stated above

Answer (score 0):

If it's okay to use two stacks, you can use one for the values and one for the operators.

When you extract a value from the input, push it on the value-stack, when you find an operator push it on the operator stack.

Then when creating the output, pop one operator from the operator stack, pop one or two (depending on the operator) values from the value stack. Output the values, output the operator. For expressions using more than a single operator, the previous operation is considered to be the first value so you only need to pop one (or zero) value next time.

Of course, this is kind of a naive way, and doesn't handle things like operator precedence.

You could also do a recursive-descent parser, which while it doesn't actually use an explicit stack uses an implicit stack in that functions are called recursively so the stack is actually the function call stack.

Comment: thanks for this but i think that there is some stupid mistake that i am making and thats why it does work, maybe i am not saving it right or something

Comment: @JackF To start with, fix the `for` loop! Then as suggested by a commenter, use the debugger to step through the code line by line while checking variables and conditions. The debugger is your friend, use it as much as possible.

Comment: oki i got it working but i have trouble figuring out what if you input like  5 * 3 + -1.2 then its not gonna work if you want to have like negative number.

Comment: @JackF If using the two-stack method I describe in my answer, you have to either push the negative value on the value stack, or use a special "negation" operator to push on the operator stack.

Comment: i updated my code, if you just could take a look i would be really thankful, and i don't use double stacks.